# Hyperledger Fabric: Cannot get string data from another chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Example. I have 2 chaincode (A, B) 
- chaincode A: generate a password hash (string) using bcrypt
- chaincode B: invoke chaincode A and get the password hash

- Test 1: I call chaincode A and get the password hash likes this: "$2a$10$e9lha95xDRV0EfQQIW9zMecZqspeA5aaI8JUf36vgUmoKXtmzs"
- Test 2: I call chaincode B to get the password hash likes this: "0Y0═*�H�=╗╔*�H�=╚╔╚B"

Anyone, please could you tell me what happened? How to fix?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you generate password hash ? Do you use random salt generated by bcrypt ?

Answer (score 1):

Chaincode must be deterministic to return same result on each host. Default bcrypt implementation generate random salt and don't meet this requirement

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using https://gowebexamples.com/password-hashing/ , I guess when the password hash sent via payload, it was encoded so I get the weird string in chain code B, I'm not sure I will investigate more, if no, I will find another hash password package.

Comment: Please read this article about stroring passwords https://medium.com/@danboterhoven/why-you-should-use-bcrypt-to-hash-passwords-af330100b861 and be aware that you can't use "Random ‘salt’ for each user" in chaincode.

Comment: Thanks @mgosk, the bcrypt generated random salt. I would say I don't compare the string hash, I use bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hash), []byte(password)) to compare. I tested this case: in chaincode A, I hash my password and store in the Couchdb, in chaincode B, I get the hash from Couchdb and compare with my password using this method bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword -> it worked successfully. As my question, the hash was generated by another chaincode then compare by bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword ... it should work but not. This's a reason why I guess something wrong in payload.